# How to add columns in between others in CSV file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I do have a CSV file row as follow

```
22727176549389059,1917,6544,**91999926,266392261**,53972147,2131,Sun Apr 28 21:00:44 PDT 2013
```

I want to add a new column in between 4th and 5th column. How can I achieve this?

```
22727176549389059,1917,6544,**91999926**,new column,**266392261**,53972147,2131,Sun Apr 28 21:00:44 PDT 2013
```

I know how to append at the end. But that is not helping...

```
import csv
all = []
with open('fileinput','rU') as csvinput:
  reader = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in csvinput), delimiter=',')
  line = 0;
  try:
    for row in reader:
  #    row.append('')
      if '\0' in row: continue
      if not row: continue
      row.append('#3')
      all.append(row)
      except csv.Error, e:
          print 'Error'
```

Comment: What about [`row.insert(5,#3)`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)? Then re-open your csv file in write mode and write out the updated rows.

Comment: Also, please check your indentation. Python is whitespace sensitive.

Comment: @thegrinner worked like a charm. Thank you very much. Indentation is beecause of copy and paste.

Answer (score 2):

Considering row as a list you can use the following

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a = a[:3] + [9,8,7] + a[3:]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7, 4, 5]
```

or

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a.insert(3, 9)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 9, 4, 5]
```

then create a new csv

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `csv.DictReader` and `DictWriter`. I employ the `StringIO` package here for demonstration. `f` would be your in file connection and `csv_out` would be your out. I create a two row csv with columns A and B, then insert a column C in between them of all -1.

```
import StringIO
import csv

orig_csv_text = """A,B
1,2
3,4
"""
# behaves like a file connection to the above string
f = StringIO.StringIO(orig_csv_text)

# empty out buffer, behaves like a new file connection
csv_out = StringIO.StringIO('')

# new column to add and the name
new_col = [-1,-1]
new_col_name = 'C'

# extract original header names from first row of csv
orig_names = [name.strip() for name in f.readline().split(',')]
# read the rows into a list
rows = list(csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=orig_names))
new_names = orig_names
# take the original names and insert the new column where you want it. 
# here I insert after the first column.
new_names.insert(1, 'C')
# create a writer object using the new names
writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_out, fieldnames=new_names, lineterminator='\n')
writer.writeheader()
# for each row in the original csv, add the new value and write it to csv_out.
for row, new_val in zip(rows, new_col):
    row[new_col_name] = new_val
    writer.writerow(row)

csv_out.getvalue()
# 'A,C,B\n1,-1,2\n3,-1,4\n'
```